# Responsive table and display flex (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How to show the scrolling of Bootstrap table using a flex container?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#responsive-tables

I need DIVS of JSFiddle example. If I remove display:flex of .flex_container and I resize the browser It works, **to appears scrolling** in low resolutions, but I can't change the structure, I need that DIV.

Any idea? (JSFiddle example)

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/49by5oL3/4/

```
<style>
.flex_container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: Red;
    }

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If you don't use the css overflow, you could use. Details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Can you just describe more? Or else you can share an image. So We can understand very well.

Comment: I want to use this model of table: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#responsive-tables with a flexbox layout

Comment: explain your question in detail. i am confused. what exactly you want. a table with responsible in horizontal way..?

Comment: This: https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/49by5oL3/5 but with display:flex

Comment: @FeKuLa Do you want the whole table in the flex concept. right?

Comment: Yes, and the horizontal scrolling bar (at specific viewport), like the bootstrap examples.

Comment: @FeKuLa. I will do it. Give me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `max-width: 100%` to #main to get a scrollbar for your table:

```
#main {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background:
    #fff;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;

    // add this:
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0aonz2k/